# Screen lag spikes when WiFi on

Tags: debian, wifi, monitors, lag

I have a strange problem: Whenever WiFi is turned on (doesn't matter if connected or not), my screen freezes for a few frames every ~2-3 seconds. This does not affect the cursor, but everything else.

Specs:
Schenker XMG A507-vsy
Debian buster/sid (x86-64)
Cinnamon 3.2.7
Kernel 4.9.0-6-amd64
CPU Intel Core i7-7700HQ
GPU Intel Corporation Device 591b
Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)

When searching for things like "wifi screen lag spikes" or similar, I of course get people who have lag spikes in online games, so that doesn't help me.

Output of `lspci -nnk`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [8086:5910] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [1558:850a]
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Skylake PCIe Controller (x16) [8086:1901] (rev 05)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:591b] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device [1558:850a]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller [8086:a12f] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller [1558:850a]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci
00:14.2 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem [8086:a131] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem [1558:850a]
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 [8086:a13a] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI [1558:850a]
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me
00:17.0 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [8086:a103] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Sunrise Point-H SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [1558:850a]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #1 [8086:a110] (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #5 [8086:a114] (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.6 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #7 [8086:a116] (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller [8086:a152] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller [1558:850a]
00:1f.2 Memory controller [0580]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC [8086:a121] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Sunrise Point-H PMC [1558:850a]
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation CM238 HD Audio Controller [8086:a171] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer CM238 HD Audio Controller [1558:850b]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus [8086:a123] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Sunrise Point-H SMBus [1558:850a]
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
01:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] [10de:1c8d] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] [1558:850a]
    Kernel modules: nouveau
02:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1142 USB 3.1 Host Controller [1b21:1242]
    Subsystem: Device [850a:1558]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8411B PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:5287] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer RTL8411B PCI Express Card Reader [1558:850a]
    Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
    Kernel modules: rtsx_pci
03:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 12)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1558:850a]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 [8086:24fd] (rev 78)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 [8086:1010]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Complete hardware info: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TFJGCLrhsOFLEfTNlbOss8aWNYpgJsZb

Comment: Right now I don't have any advice to offer, but could you please update your post with the output of `lspci -nnk`? (This will show, for all listed components, their numeric PCI IDs and the name of the kernel driver in use.)

Comment: D _ o _ n _ e _ .

Comment: I tried switching my network manager over to wicd, that didn't help.

Comment: Can you try to boot with a different kernel...? Grub should give you such advanced options.

Comment: I have the options "Linux 4.16.0-1" and "Linux 4.9.0-4", both regular and recovery. Recovery is console only, 4.9.0-4 seems to change nothing.

Comment: No, it's 4.9.0-6.

Comment: You can try with 4.16. You might also have kernel 3.16 somewhere in your grub or in `/boot`

Comment: Considering the cursor does not lag I would assume its not the screen but the GPU at issue. Causes could be bad driver interaction or bus errors. Bus errors would probably should up in journalcrl.

Note that iwlwifi is a binary blob and so sometimes that leads to unforeseen compatibility issues. https://wiki.debian.org/iwlwifi

Comment: Here we go: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi Its supported.

Comment: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/iwlwifi/linux-firmware.git/commit/

Comment: I added `/usr/share/hwdata/pci.ids` into the question.

Comment: So, @jdwolf, do I have to download one of those drivers or do you mean that it should already be installed?

Comment: @Fabian No, just grab your distros updates as normal. I just put that there to show which versions are currently out.

Comment: New info! I found some screen recordings: The oldest two have no lag, then there's one where I had "wobbly windows" installed, all after that have the lag! So maybe installing wobbly windows messed something up that wasn't corrected when I uninstalled it again! I still don't know why it only happens with WiFi on, but that could be the cause. And I don't even have to do anything different next time I install the OS, I could even install Debian again, I just can't install wobbly windows ever (which I didn't plan anyway, I just had it for a few minutes for fun).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>The most likely cause was installing the extension "[Wobbly windows](https://cinnamon-spices.linuxmint.com/extensions/view/24)". Even after uninstalling, some change that was done while installing it probably still caused problems.</s>

It does show a warning that it isn't compatible with the current OS version, so I can't say I wasn't warned. It's just strange that it doesn't undo all changes when uninstalling it.

The only fix I found was reinstalling Debian.

Edit: It was not "wobbly windows", because after reinstalling Debian, I got the same issue after a bit of setup, but I somehow fixed it again without reinstalling again. It's very likely an applet's fault, but I don't know which one. If you have the same problem, try removing some applets and if that doesn't work, try uninstalling them.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a hardware issue - interference of some kind perhaps. Something not quite exactly like your symptoms happened to a colleague of mine and to me some three years ago, and just *changing the WiFi channel* "fixed" the problem. We both were using the same model of Dell laptop (I think Latitude E5500?).

This might or might not be of help, and even if it was, it might well be that there's an underlying issue.

## Update

I've been doing a bit of research, and my case wasn't really germane since my colleague remembers the *mouse* freezing too, moving in jumps - so everything worked and just the video update was amiss. You on the other hand have video freezes but no mouse trouble.

This still points to hardware IMHO, just a different piece of hardware. It might be a IRQ conflict, which you should be able to both solve from the BIOS setup screen, and notice from the logs:

```
dmesg | grep -i irq
```

You can also verify using `lspci -vvv`. For a very quick check,

```
lspci -vvv | grep IRQ | sort | uniq -c
```

*should* ideally return all 1's (some conflicts are less problematic than others though).

Comment: I executed `sudo iwconfig wlp4s0 channel 1` and rebooted, but it didn't help, same with channel 6.

Comment: I assume varying the screen resolution - which changes *some* internal frequencies in the graphic hardware - also avails nothing? The last test, just to be really sure, would be booting with a different OS. If everything fails, I fear it's technical service time.

Comment: Nope, doesn't help. For now I could always use my phone for WiFi and then use USB tethering, like I did on my old laptop, but in the long term that's not what I bought a new laptop for.

Comment: if you can reproduce the effect with, say, a diagnostic or restore disk, that would be enough to ask for warranty repair or even replacement in my country (within two years of purchase). Have you inquired about warranty terms?

Comment: I will try the live boot this weekend.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest booting your system once using a [live bootable usb](https://www.electronproton.com/how-to-create-linux-live-usb/) and use your Wifi once.

If the problem persists then it is assumed as hardware issue else driver issue.

Comment: I get no lag spikes on a live system! \o/ That still doesn't explain why I got them before. Might be because of "wobbly windows", but I uninstalled it.

Comment: Since there was no answer that solved my problem, you get the bounty.